# Looking for the definition of `COMPILE_WPRINTF`

Tags: c, gnu, libc

I was going through source code of glibc implementations of `printf` like functions, as `vsnprintf`, `fprintf`, `vfprintf` and such, all of them included `#ifndef COMPILE_WPRINTF` or `#ifdef COMPILE_WPRINTF`.

Tried to look for the definitions of `COMPILE_WPRINTF` online but came out empty.
I figure it has something to do with wide character type `wchar_t` (hence the `W` in `COMPILE_WPRINTF`?) since for example, [vfprintf](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c) include the following code:

```
#ifndef COMPILE_WPRINTF
...
# define CHAR_T     char
...
#else
...
# define CHAR_T     wchar_t
```

But I'm very curious to know where\when this definition is defined, can someone point me to it?

Comment: These symbols must be defined on the gcc command line. I.e. `gcc -c -D COMPILE_WPRINTF myfile.c`

Comment: @Frankie_C can you please provide me a reference? also, `libc` often is already compiled and liked to c program rather than compiled every time gcc is compiling a program, am I missing something?

Comment: This is simply a technique used to create conditional compilations. This specific symbols is used to compile some code using `wprintf` instead of `printf` related code. In this way changing a definition on command line you can use same make file to compile different versions of code (provided that the code uses `#ifdef` or similar preprocessor constructs.

Comment: You don't have to specify anything, someone used it when compiled the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdio-common/vfwprintf.c` looks like this:

```
#include <wctype.h>
#define COMPILE_WPRINTF 1
#include "vfprintf.c"
```

In essence, `stdio-common/vfprintf.c` is compiled twice (for each build variant), once without `COMPILE_WPRINTF` defined, once with`COMPILE_WPRINTF`.  The code was written this way because a lot of the sources are shared between the two variants.